# Magnitude of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have a basic linear algebra question. Suppose that $ u \in \mathbb{R}^n $, and $ P(u, V) $ is the orthogonal projection of $ u $ onto a linear subspace $ V $. I would like to prove that
$$
\|P(u,V)\| = \text{max} \left\{ |\langle u, v \rangle| : v \in V, \|v\| = 1 \right\}.
$$
I know that $ P(u, V) $ is the unique vector $ w $ such that $ \|v-w\| $ is minimal, and I am sure I will need this here, but I don't see a good way to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

If $P_{V}x$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $V$, then $(x-P_{V}x)\perp V$. And $P_{V}x \in V$. Therefore
$$
                x = (x-P_{V}x)+P_{V}x,\;\;\; (x-P_{V}x)\perp P_{V}x.
$$
That gives
$$
                    \|x\|^2 = \|x-P_{V}x\|^2+\|P_{V}x\|^2 \ge \|P_{V}x\|^2.
$$
Also, if $v \in V$, then $(u-P_{V}u)\perp v$ implies
$$
            (u,v) = (u-P_{V}u,v)+(P_{V}u,v)=(P_{V}u,v).
$$
Therefore, if $v \in V$ with $\|v\|=1$,
$$
   |(u,v)|=|(P_{V}u,v)|\le \|P_{V}u\|\|v\|=\|P_{V}u\|.
$$
And, if $P_{V}u \ne 0$, take $v=\frac{1}{\|P_{V}u\|}P_{V}u$ to obtain
$$
             |(u,v)| = \|P_{V}u\|.
$$